# How To Define A Flexible delegate field with multiple optional parameters?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I'm developing a simulation game where I have some conditional methods in various classes which I want to use them for random in-game events.

My aim is creating a user-friendly event class where users can add events via XML serializing (that part is good to go). So I'm trying to keep things simple and generic as much as possible. I got some conditional methods in various classes like

```
public class Person
{
    static bool IsOlderThan(int age) {/*...*/}
}

public class Faction
{
    static bool HasRelationMoreThan(Faction faction,float value) {/*...*/}
}
```

and so on...

I must define a Func<> parameter or another delegate which can accept these methods with different scope of parameters, instead of defining a different field for every single one of them. TL;DR: I need a delegate type which accepts any method as value.

Is there any way to create a flexible, generic method reference like this?

Comment: What parameters will you pass when you call the delegate? What if you only passed 2 parameters but the delegate expects 3?

Comment: I meant *any* numbers of *any* parameters :) That's the problem I'm wondering.

Comment: Can you show some code that uses this mechanic? What kind of code do you want to write that makes use of this "multiple optional parameter" thingy?

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't many options for that: either define separate delegate for every combination of parameters you're going to use or define delegate which would accept array of `Object` instances where you can put your parameters.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated my question and added some examples to clarify what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MulticastDelegate class. It's a base class for all delegates.
But be careful. MulticastDelegates are invoked via DynamicInvoke(), which works slower than Invoke(). And you also have to control number and types of parameters passed into DynamicInvoke() because it can cause runtime errors.

```
private void TestMulticastDelegate()
{
    Func<int, bool> function1 = IntToBool;
    Func<string, bool> function2 = StringToBool;
    Func<int, string, bool> function3 = IntAndStringToBool;

    int intArg = 1;
    string stringArg = "someString";

    MulticastDelegate d;

    d = new Func<int, bool>(IntToBool);
    bool res1 = d.DynamicInvoke(intArg).Equals(function1(intArg)); // always true

    d = new Func<string, bool>(StringToBool);
    bool res2 = d.DynamicInvoke(stringArg).Equals(function2(stringArg)); // always true

    d = new Func<int, string, bool>(IntAndStringToBool);
    bool res3 = d.DynamicInvoke(intArg, stringArg).Equals(function3(intArg, stringArg)); // always true
}

private bool IntToBool(int i)
{
    return i == 0;
}

private bool StringToBool(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}

private bool IntAndStringToBool(int i, string s)
{
    return i.ToString().Equals(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```